# How do I display PHP-cURL errors?

Tags: php, curl, post, request

What could be causes of the page not loading? I'm currently sending a request to my bot which sends me a response back but somehow, if the bot is online and working, the page doesn't load. Is there a way to get the error? I have a cPanel and display_errors is `1`. Any other ideas?

This is one of my requests:

```
function getData($Id) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://IPAdress:8000/Data/".$Id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

   return $server_output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

curl_errno() and curl_error() usually suffice,

```php
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$errstr=null;
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    $errstr = curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
if(isset($errstr)){
    echo $errstr;
}
```

sometimes you can get even more information  by adding CURLOPT_VERBOSE

```
$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
$errstr=null;
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    $errstr = curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch)." verbose: ".$stderr;
}
curl_close ($ch);
if(isset($errstr)){
    echo $errstr;
}
```

but that's usually kindof overkill

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems to print the error! But the whole website isn't loading when the bot is online - even pages I don't use cURL aren't loading. Any ideas on the cause of this?

Comment: @Neeko do you have access to the php errorlog? anyway could lots of things, could be something as stupid as hitting a die();, could also be that it's crashing inside a ob_start(); , but usually it's because display_errors is 0/off, does phpinfo() actually confirm that display_errors is 1? (regardless of what your cpanel setting is)

Comment: Hey, display errors is on (checked with phpinfo) - no error_log is being generated. I don't use any ob_start() or something similiar to that. Website works flawless if bot is offline and stops working if it's online, pages are perma-loading and not a single error (besides that I can't even reach the page to see if there's an error).

Comment: @Neeko ohh perma-loading? then it's probably a CURLOPT_TIMEOUT / CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT issue, try ```curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>3,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>5));``` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - sadly that didn't work either. If I try to go from the hopepage to a page that sends requests it's perma-loading and during that time I'm always on the homepage.

Comment: @Neeko hmm what happens if you run `set_time_limit(6);` does it make any difference?

Comment: After some minutes I've got a complete website crash with error code 524. I've looked up a bit and saw this: _Any HTTP request that doesn't receive a response from the origin server for over 100 seconds (or over 600 seconds for enterprise customers) will be timed out and you'll see the 524 A Timeout Occurred error._ - Does that mean that my bot doesn't send a response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234029/discussion-between-neeko-and-hanshenrik).